# umfpack: An error occurred: numeric factorization: not enough memory

Tags: matrix, memory, scilab, factorization, umfpack

I'm having a problem while running a Scilab code.
As title suggests, I get the error `numeric factorization: not enough memory`, related to the umfpack function.

In task manager I see a memory usage around 3GB (my system has 16GB).
Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: What is the order of the matrices involved in the problem?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are attempting to use `umfpack` with matrices which are too big, and then it is unable to allocate the memory required (probably more than the 13GB you still have available).

See also https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/8972/21926